# How to install a Lexmark z600 series printer?

Tags: 64-bit, printing, 32-bit, lexmark

It has been a headache trying to install this printer. All the tutorials I found are for older versions of Ubuntu, and none of them work.

How can I install this printer?

**Edit:**  [HOWTO: Install PITA Lexmark Z600 Z615 and Dell Photo Printer 720](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=215657)

[Setup Lexmark Z600 and X series printer on Ubuntu](http://Setup%20Lexmark%20Z600%20and%20X%20series%20printer%20on%20Ubuntu) (i tried this one, only that it was translated to spanish, but it was the same instructions)

[HOWTO: Lexmark Printers](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=49714)

I always get an error when extracting the converted tars with all of the tuts, invalid argument or the file doesn't exist.

**Looks like, i was missing some ia32 libs .. and that caused the errors with the tar files, anyways i still can't print now i get this, *cups-insecure-filter***

[How to install Lezmark Z600 series printer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=821831)

Here, the OP offers 2 debs, i installed them on a 32 bit Ubuntu install, now the printer gets recognized but still can't print, 'cause i'm missing a filter, "rastertoz600".

Comment: Is there anything special to this printer except the fact that you already have it? Lexmark printers have always been a pain to use with Linux and there's no indication that this will change. New printers are available for chump change and most of them will match your printer's specification. E.g. this one http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/sg/en/ho/WF06b/18972-18972-236251-64340-64340-4066042-4066379.html , availabe for ~30 USD. If you're not doing this out of morbid curiosity but actually want to get printing ASAP, I'd consider a new printer with better Linux support.

Comment: can you add to your question which tutorial you've tried - for example, have you tried this one? http://finebushpeople.net/LexmarkZ600

Comment: @fossfreedom ok i'll add which tutorials i've read.

Comment: @nem75 that's the thing.. i don't want (or can't afford right now anyway) to buy a new one, this one still does it's job, and i don't want to boot into Windows just to get printing done.

Comment: does this work: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters/LexmarkPrinters ?

Comment: @Rinzwind nope... i tried it too and is pretty much the same as the threads on ubuntuforums.

Comment: though i was missing some 32bit libs, but still.. doesn't work :(.

Comment: try this thread for your insecure filter error - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1313291

Comment: with 1800+ rep you should know by now you should answer and accept the answer to your question and not edit the answern into the question Uri Herrera ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind yeah i know, i was editing the answer and printing some stuff :P

Comment: @Uri Herrera: I hear you, but as I said ... 30 bucks ... well, to each his own. All the best with your efforts. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HOWTO: Lexmark Printers Page 69 post 68 by VietCanada](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=49714&page=70) this worked!.

1. install libstdc++5 from synaptic.
2. install [getlibs-all.deb.](http://www.4shared.com/file/WizxlgkB/getlibs-all.html)
3. install [lexmark.z600-0.4.deb.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters/LexmarkPrinters?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=lexmark.z600-0.4.deb)
4. go to
   System/Administration/Printing.
5. choose Lexmark z600 printer

Only seems to work for 64 bit though, on a 32 bit Ubuntu 11.04 Install, the  package *lexmark.z600-0.4.deb* can't be installed due to a missing dependency **libcupsys2** which i can't install.

Comment: The getlibs-all.deb link 404s! However I managed to install the lexmark.z600-0.4.deb on 32bit and everything worked for me :)

Comment: Yeah, the host doesn't exist anymore I just updated the Link though, but glad it worked without it.

Answer (score 2):

These steps just worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit with a very old Lexmark X1180 printer/scanner (I only want to print BTW).

1) Install `libstdc++5` from synaptic.

2) Remove existing `z600xxxx packages` from synaptic (I think I had previously tried to install an older version of the z600 drivers)

3) Install `lexmark.z600-0.4.deb`.

4) Insert USB cable to printer.

5) Go to Printing via Ubuntu search.

6) Added new printer, chose the connected printer, then selected Lexmark manufacturer and right at the bottom the z600 driver from the installed package appeared in the list.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the lexmark z600 or dell 720 (rebranded name) work in ubuntu 16 or 18,19,20 you have to:

1. Install gdebi and download the 32 bit [driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters/LexmarkPrinters?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=lexmark.z600-0.4.deb) with:

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi lexmark.z600-0.4.deb
```

2. Install this 32bit libraries and restart cups

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386
sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2:i386
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

3. Open "Printers" having your printer connected, Click Add, select your printer

4. Click Settings (gear) of the printer, Printer details, Select from database, then Lexmark. Select the new driver at the end of the Lexmark list

If printer does not print, look for errors

```
cat /var/log/cups/error_log | grep "error while"
```