# How to get Lexmark Z715 to work with 22.04

Tags: drivers, printing

I'm struggling to get my Lexmark Z715 printer to work with 22.04. It seems folks have been able to get it to work in previous versions, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

It gets detected and installed as a 'generic text only printer'. I've tried uninstalling and installing the drivers multiple times. I've tried the z600 and the z700 debian packages, but nada.

Looks like some of the dependencies in the past already come installed in 22.04, so I'm just plain stuck at this point on what might be missing.

The closest I'll get to printing is it'll render the job and then then not do anything else. I wonder if there is another driver that is an alternative I could use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. Follow the steps at the end of this thread https://askubuntu.com/a/872719/1629661 to install the 32 bit drivers (even if your system is 64 bit). Just make sure to install the z700 and not the z600 one referenced in this thread.

I used Gdebi to install the z700 package after downloading it.

Make sure to uninstall the printer and install again and to switch from the generic text only printer to the Lexmark 700 series driver.

Many hours of frustration, but gave new life to an old model